# How to use Roboto Thin in Google Docs

Tags: fonts, google-docs

Is there a way to use Roboto Thin font in a "Google Docs" document?

I fount a way to add Roboto font (via "More Fonts...") but I have not found a way to set the Thin or Light version.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is now possible to use intermediate (i.e. light/semibold) font weights in Google docs. Click the fonts menu, and then click the arrow to the right of your desired font to select the weight you would like (this arrow is only present on fonts with other available weights).

[image: screeenshot]

Answer (score 5):

It is is not currently possible to use different font weights in Google Docs. However, it has been requested in [Google Product forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/C2VHYFHHvTI).